# Can I place a switch inside a switch?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have an assignment for class due and I very confused. I have done the full assignment myself but this one bit has got me.

Basically I have it so you click on the first artist, which then follows to the venue (depending on the artist), then depending on the venue it flows to the date and then depending on the date it flows to the ticket amount and ticket cost.

So far I have this:

```
function fillVenue() {

    //retrieves index of selected artist and target element to be populated
    var artist  = document.getElementById("artist");
    var venue   = document.getElementById("venue");
    var date    = document.getElementById("date");
    var ticket  = document.getElementById("tickets");
    var cost    = document.getElementById("cost");

    // clears data from each category
    venue.options.length = 0;
    date.options.length = 0;
    ticket.options.length = 0;
    cost.options.length = 0;

    // clearing event
    venue.onchange = null;

    // Collect and Calculate Total
    function costTotal() {
        if (ticket.selectedIndex != 0 && cost.selectedIndex != 0) {
            var costTotal       = document.getElementById("costTotal");
            var ticketCount     = ticket.value;
            var costAmount      = (cost.value).substr(1);
            costTotal.value = " £" + ticketCount * costAmount;
        }
    }
    ticket.onchange = costTotal;
    cost.onchange   = costTotal;


    switch (artist.selectedIndex) {
        case 0:
        // list begins
        // allows user to select venue
            var venueList   = ["Select Venue"]; 

        // allows user to select date
            var dateList    = ["Select Date"];

        // allows user to select ticket amount      
            var ticketList  = ["Select Tickets"];

        // allows user to select price of ticket
            var costList    = ["Select Price"];

        // fills each category  
            fillList(venue, venueList);
            fillList(date, dateList);
            fillList(ticket, ticketList);
            fillList(cost, costList);
            break;

        case 1:
            // madonna

        // allows user to select venue
            var venueList   = ["Select Venue", "London"];

         // allows user to select date
         var dateList   = ["Select Date", "17th July", "18th July"];

         // allows user to select ticket amount
        var ticketList  = ["Select Tickets", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

        // allows user to select price of ticket
            var costList    = ["Select Price", "£30", "£45", "£70"];

        // fills each category
            fillList(venue, venueList);
            fillList(date, dateList);
            fillList(ticket, ticketList);
            fillList(cost, costList);
            break;

        case 2:
            //Rod Stewart


        // allows user to select venue
         var venueList  = ["Select Venue", "Manchester", "Glasgow"];

        // allows user to select date
         var dateList   = ["Select Date"]

        // allows user to select ticket amount
         var ticketList = ["Select Tickets", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

        // allows user to select price of ticket 
         var costList   = ["Select Price", "£30", "£45", "£70"];

         //fills each category
            fillList(venue, venueList);
            fillList(date, dateList);
            fillList(ticket, ticketList);
            fillList(cost, costList);

            //  onchange event - selected Rod Stewart
            venue.onchange = function () {
                var dateList;
                switch(venue.selectedIndex) {
                    case 0: dateList = ["Select Date"]; break;
                    case 1: dateList = ["Select Date", "18th July", "20th July"]; break;
                    case 2: dateList = ["Select Date", "22nd July", "23rd July"]; break;
                }
                fillList(date, dateList);
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            //Guns and Roses
            var venueList   = ["Select Venue", "London"];
            var dateList    = ["Select Date", "10th July"];
            var ticketList  = ["Select Tickets", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
            var costList    = ["Select Price", "£88"];
            fillList(venue, venueList);
            fillList(date, dateList);
            fillList(ticket, ticketList);
            fillList(cost, costList);
            break;

        case 4:
            // Oasis
            var venueList   = ["Select Venue", "London", "Glasgow", "Nottingham"];
            var dateList    = ["Select Date"];
            var ticketList  = ["Select Tickets", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
            var costList    = ["Select Price"];

            fillList(venue, venueList);
            fillList(date, dateList);
            fillList(ticket, ticketList);
            fillList(cost, costList);


            venue.onchange = function  () {
                var dateList;
                switch(venue.selectedIndex) {
                    case 0: dateList = ["Select Date"]; break;
                    case 1: dateList = ["Select Date", "23rd July", "24th July"]; break ;
                    case 2: dateList = ["Select Date", "21st July"]; break;
                    case 3: dateList = ["Select Date", "18th July", "19th July"]; break;
                }

            cost.onchange = function  () {
                var costList;
                switch(cost) {
                    case 0: costList = ["Select Price"]; 
                    case 1: costList = ["Select Price", "£45", "£60"];
                    case 2: costList = ["Select Price", "£45", "£65"]; 
                    case 3: costList = ["Select Price", "£25", "£45", "£65"]; 
                }
            }
                fillList(date, dateList);
                fillList(cost, costList);
            }
            break;


        case 5:
            //Beyonce
            var venueList   = ["Select Venue", "Glasgow", "Manchester", "Birmingham", "London"];
            var dateList    = ["Select Date"];
            var ticketList  = ["Select Tickets", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
            var costList    = ["Select Price"];
            fillList(venue, venueList);
            fillList(date, dateList);
            fillList(ticket, ticketList);
            fillList(cost, costList);
            break;
    }
}

function fillList(list,items) {
    list.options.length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var option = new Option(items[i]);
        list.options[i] = option;
    }   
}
```

They complete code works up to the 'Oasis' drop down. Where the dates and the venue just don't add up. In fact the price just stays at 'select price' and no prices appear.

I was thinking about adding an IF statement, but I am not too sure if that is a) possible b) a good idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: also: I have been told that there are other ways to do this, but preferably (if it is an option) I would like to keep the similar kind of coding I currently have.

Comment: That wall of codes... If you are just wanting to know if you can place a switch inside a switch, the short answer is yes you can.

Comment: The question at the bottom, on asking how to do it. Sorry forgot to add it to the top! :)

Comment: well in your cost.onchange you declare costList so it becomes a local variable which makes so it will not use/fill the outer costList variable with the list, move your `fillList(cost,costList)` into the onchange function.

Comment: Break that one big `fillVenue` into at least 6 or 7 functions. Dramatically improves readability and maintainability.

Comment: Would breaking the function into 6 or 7 functions, help with it working though?

Answer (score 0):

a) It IS possible to place switch inside switch. Why shouldn't it?

```
switch (something) {
    case 1:
        switch (something else) {
             case "A":
                 // do it
                 break;
             case "B":
                 // do other things
                 break;
             default:
                 // maybe do this or that
                 break;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        // anything else
        break
    default: 
        // whatever
        break
}
```

b) `if` inside `case`s is also possible.

c) Your complete structure just seems so wrong... you don't seem to do different things in each case, just the same thing with different parameters. If so, don't use switch/case or if/else, but create a function that takes the parameters and acts accordingly. It's called DRY: "Don't repeat yourself". Don't write any code twice or trice. If you need to, that's clearly code that belongs into some function.

Store that data in another format. Multi-dimensions array for example. JavaScript objects. Or use databases if possible - that's what they're for after all.

Comment: thanks @Derek朕會功夫 for corrercting that mess! Actually you were right - this WAS typed on my phone. Not a valid excuse after all, as there is autocorrect, I was just too lazy to switch it to english...